# When I log a prop to the console, I don't get the props but .0.0.2.0

Tags: reactjs

I have a CoreLayout smart component, and a Banner dumb component as a child, written as follow (I only kept the relevant slices of the code):

```
class CoreLayout extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    closeBanner(e, type) {
      e.stopPropagation()
      console.log(type)
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
              <Banner type='bannerA'/>
              <Banner type='bannerB'/>
          </div>       
        )
    }
}
```

And a simple Banner component:

```
const Banner = ({type, closeBanner}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <span onClick={ (e, type) => closeBanner(e, type) }>close</span>
            <span>A message</span>
        </div>
    )  
}
```

My problem is that instead of logging 'bannerA' or 'bannerB' to the console when I click on the closing , I see things like 0.0.2.0.0 or 0.0.3.0.0 depending on the banner I click.

However, if I log the type in the Banner component, it is able to log the right type to the console.

Has anyone an idea about this behavior ? Let me know if you need more details on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is here:

```
onClick = {(e, type) => close(e,type)}
```

`onClick = {(e, type) => ... }` here `e` and `type`, these two parameters will get passed by a `onClick` function, here `type` will not be the same as the type you are getting from parent component, type will be just the `parameter name` in `onClick` function.

In the first line you are `destructuring` the `props object`:

```
const Banner = ({type, closeBanner}) => {
```

This `type` will have the value, you passed from parent component.

Write it like this:

```
const Banner = ({type, closeBanner}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <span onClick={ (e) => closeBanner(e, type) }>close</span>
            <span>A message</span>
        </div>
    )  
}
```

Also you need to pass `closeBanner` function from parent:

```
<Banner type='bannerA' closeBanner={this.closeBanner}/>
```

Comment: I see. Indeed, just removing the type parameter solved the issue:
(e) => closeBanner(e, type)
Thanks!